# How to close details tag on mouse click out of the tag

Tags: html, css

How do I unexpand a [`<details>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details) tag when the user clicks somewhere outside of it?

I guess there is no CSS solution so a JavaScript solution would be fine.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add an event listener for `click` that checks whether the event target is a child of the tag, and if not, remove the `open` attribute:

```js
var details = document.querySelector('details');
document.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  if(!details.contains(e.target)){
    details.removeAttribute('open')
  }
})
```

```css
details{
  border:1px solid;
}
```

```html
<details>
  <summary>Click to open</summary>
  <p>Click somewhere else (not this) to close the dropdown</p>
</details>
```

If you have multiple `detail` tags, you can use `querySelectorAll` to select all the elements and tell whether one was clicked outside of the tag with the user of [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```js
var details = [...document.querySelectorAll('details')];
document.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  if(details.some(f => f.contains(e.target)).length != 0){
    details.forEach(f => f.removeAttribute('open'));
  }
})
```

```css
details{
  border:1px solid;
}
```

```html
<details>
  <summary>Click to open</summary>
  <p>Click somewhere else (not this) to close the dropdown</p>
</details>

<details>
  <summary>Click to open 2</summary>
  <p>Click somewhere else (not this) to close the dropdown</p>
</details>

<details>
  <summary>Click to open 3</summary>
  <p>Click somewhere else (not this) to close the dropdown</p>
</details>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I want but I cant make it work on my end. Its the kind of codes that have to be added inside head or right before the body closing tag?

Comment: @CainNuke You have to put it before the `body` closing tag.

Comment: You can put the JS code anywhere you want, but you should wrap it into a [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event) event listener to make sure that the JS runs after the HTML code appears on the page.

Comment: it kinda works now but it will close even if the click is within the details area. I cant figure out why.

Comment: okay I fixed it by changing it to this line: `if(!details.some(f => f.contains(e.target)))` however there is still a little issue left. I have multiple details tag and when I open one I would like it to close if I open another one as well so there are not 2 open details tags at the same time. How can I work this around?

Comment: @CainNuke I tested the code with the changed code and it does not let two details tag to be open at the same time.

Comment: @CainNuke Yes, with the updated `if` statement.

Comment: thats weird. Its different on my end. Where did you place the code?

Comment: @CainNuke have you tried running the second snippet? It would be very helpful if you provided an online example (e.g, a jsfiddle) fr me to reproduce.

Comment: the 2nd snippet is what i tried but modified. i will provide the example.

Comment: I created a fiddle but I cant even make the code work here https://jsfiddle.net/f2q98o0d/

Comment: @CainNuke Try [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sr86zgvx/)

Comment: I tried but it still has the same issue. If you click anywhere inside the tag it will close it too. The tag should close only if the click is made outside that tag. My modified code does it but then the other tags wont close when one of them is open.